# How do I get a webpage redirected to another landing after Metamask connect?

Tags: redirect, metamask

So let's say someone visits a website and gets a wallet connect popup (Metamask), is there a way to redirect them to another page/landing right after wallet is connected? Like using wallet connection as a trigger. I guess it's possible in JS.